# Ruby reflection composition: call original method from redefined method

Tags: ruby, reflection, cop

### A bit of context first

I have a class `Phone` that defines a method `advertise` like this:

```
class Phone
  def advertise(phone_call)
    'ringtone'
  end
end
```

I would like to have some adaptations for this method.
For example when the user is in a quiet environment, the phone should vibrate and not ring.
To do so, I define modules like

```
module DiscreetPhone    
  def advertise_quietly (phone_call)
    'vibrator'
  end
end
```

Then my program can do

```
# add the module to the class so that we can redefine the method
Phone.include(DiscreetPhone) 
# redefine the method with its adaptation
Phone.send(:define_method, :advertise, DiscreetPhone.instance_method(:advertise_quietly ))
```

Of course for this example I hardcoded the class and module's name but they should be parameters of a function.

And so, an execution example would give:

```
phone = Phone.new
phone.advertise(a_call) # -> 'ringtone'
# do some adaptation stuff to redefine the method
...
phone.advertise(a_call) # -> 'vibrator'
```

### Finally coming to my question

I want to have an adaptation that call the original function and append something to its result. I would like to write it like

```
module ScreeningPhone
  def advertise_with_screening (phone_call)
    proceed + ' with screening'
  end
end
```

But I don't know what the `proceed` call should do or even where should I define it.

- I'm using Ruby 2.3.0 on Windows.
- `proceed` could be replaced by something else but I'd like to keep it as clean as possible in the module that defines the adaptation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this approach is way too complex, and an inappropriate use of `Module`s.

I recommend thinking about a simpler way to implement this.

One simple way is to just include all the methods in the Phone class.

Or, you could use a hash as a lookup table for ring strategies:

```
class Phone

    attr_accessor :ring_strategy

    RING_STRATEGIES = {
        ringtone:  -> { ring_with_tone },
        discreet:  -> { ring_quietly },
        screening: -> { ring_with_tone; ring_screening_too }
        # ...
    }

    def initialize(ring_strategy = :ringtone)
        @ring_strategy = ring_strategy
    end

    def ring
        RING_STRATEGIES[:ring_strategy].()
    end

end
```

Comment: Yes there is probably an easier way but I haven't found it yet and I actually need to use the reflection's features of Ruby in this project.
I can not include all methods in the `Phone` class because I would like to still call the `advertise` method. It must be its behavior that changes, not the way I call it.

Comment: When you say "I actually need to use the reflection's features of Ruby in this project.", is the reason a technical one or some other one?  If technical, can you share what it is? I'm editing my answer to include a lambda approach that might work well for you.

Comment: I've added a screening: entry that shows calling the "original" method plus added functionality.  I also made some corrections.

Comment: The reason is simple: it is a school project about Reflection in Ruby :)
Nice approach that you showed me here. But I'm not suppose to change the `Phone` class's file.
However I could create an alias for the `advertise` method, then dynamically replace the `advertise` method with the one executing the `RING_STRATEGIES[:ring_strategy].()`. Of course, I should also add the Hash to the Phone class.

Comment: I just wish for you and your classmates that you view these assigments as tools for learning the Ruby language and not recommended approaches to problem solving.

Comment: I solved my problem with the inspiration you gave me. So I'll accept your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [prepending](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) your module instead of including it.

Instead of using `define_method` as a sort of ersatz `alias_method`, just call the method `advertise` in your modules too.

Within your `advertise` method, you can call `super` to call up the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: This is a good idea but then, when the user leaves the quiet environment, I should un-include the module. And this is not possible in Ruby I think.

Comment: If that's a use case then I don't think inheritance / modules are the right way at all